# How to get data from QML to C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I try to write some application using FileDialog and I have to get file urls in my C++ class. I try to do this in this way:

```
 FileDialog {
                id: fileDialog
                objectName: "fileDialog"
                selectMultiple: true
                signal getFiles(var urls)
                title: qsTr("Open file")
                nameFilters: [qsTr("MP3 files (*.mp3)"), qsTr("All files (*.*)")]
                onAccepted: getFiles(fileDialog.fileUrls)
            }
```

........................................

```
 class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
 public slots:
    void addToPlaylist (const QList<QUrl> & urls){
        for(int i = 0; i < urls.length(); ++i)
            qDebug() << "Get\n";
    }
};
```

............................................

```
 QObject *fileDialog = root->findChild<QObject *>("column")->findChild<QObject *>("row")->findChild<QObject *>("openButton")->findChild<QObject*>("fileDialog");
    MyClass myClass;
    QObject::connect(fileDialog, SIGNAL(getFiles(QVariant)), &myClass, SLOT(addToPlaylist(QList<QUrl>)));
```

I found solution but I do not understand. Can someone explain me in my example?

> just a question (and maybe solution), why do you need to define a
>   signal in QML for this? can’t you simply call the c++ slot and pass
>   the URL list directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,you are trying to pass a list of urls from qml to c++. These are the ways.

1)Make sure that you make an object of `MyClass` available to QML by calling `QQmlContext::setContextProperty()` and registering that object.

Example:

```
 QQuickView view;
 MyClass myObj;
 view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myObj", &myObj);
```

Then you can call your `MyClass::addToPlaylist()` from QML like this.

```
FileDialog{onAccepted: myObj.addToPlaylist(fileDialog.fileUrls);}
```

[Reference: Embedding C++ Objects into QML with Context Properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html)

2)Make the `FileDialog` instance emit a signal whenever user selects some files from QML. Now this signal needs to be connected to the slot of an object of `MyClass`. In order to do this, you need to have pointers to both `FileDialog` instance and object of `MyClass` object.

You are getting pointer to an instance of `FileDialog` by doing this.

```
QObject *fileDialog = root->findChild<QObject *>("column")->findChild<QObject *>("row")->findChild<QObject *>("openButton")->findChild<QObject*>("fileDialog");
```

Now you are connecting the signal and slot. Thats it.

Comment: I've never had success making the `SIGNAL`/`SLOT` method work for passing a list of URLs...